# CPU usage increasing over time

Tags: python, performance

I have a python program that is running for many days.  Memory usage does not increase by very much, however the program becomes slower and slower.  Is there a tool or utility that will list all function calls and how long they take to complete?  Something like [guppy/heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/) but for CPU usage.

Comment: cProfile is in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit2**

I just saw your actual question is answered as in '[How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)'

---

Sure, use profile.py.

```
import profile

def myfunction():
    bla bla bla

profile.run('myfunction()')
```

see also [profilers](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) and [tips on performance](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips).

**Edit:**
Above example is for one function.
You can profile and run your script from the commandline with cProfile with:

```
python -m cProfile myscript.py
```

Your program/script could look also like the following for profiling always when run:

```
def myfunction():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)

def myotherfunction():
    for i in range(200):
        print(i)

def main():
    """ main program to run over several days """
    for _ in range(3):
        myfunction()

    myotherfunction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile.run('main()') # will execute your program
                          # and show profiling results afterwards
```

Comment: But i want to run this over my entire application over the course of days.  +1 anyway.

Comment: You can, but it will probably slow down your program even more because of the overhead. Can't you run it just for a while, check where the bottlenecks are and work on them?

Answer (score 0):

get the pid of the process

ps -ef | grep "processname" | awk '{print $2}

and then see which calls in the program are taking more time.

strace -c -p "pid"

you can even run the whole script with

strace -c script.file